# /Писать за меня код не надо/ Как вывести элементы, которые появились в директории за определенное время?

Tags: perl

В общем, необходимо реализовать следующую тулзу: По сути, это `ls`, только отличие вот в чем:

`nel 100`

Данная команда должна вывести только те элементы, которые появились в данной директории за последние 100 минут.

Просто подскажите, пожалуйста, что вообще можно придумать?

У меня в голове только 1 мысль: смотреть атрибуты каждого файла. Может еще есть какой вариант?

Comment: общего решения нет. Можно апроксимировать задачу до «вывести файлы у которых mtime больше, чем (текущее время - k минут)»; если придерживаться текущей формулировки строго, то наверно придётся писать демона, который мониторит изменения ФС, на linux, например, можно это сделать inotify'ем.

Comment: Решением было использовать функции readdir + stat. Спасибо за помощь https://vk.com/ls000

Comment: Поместите сюда сами ответ на свой вопрос. Это может оказаться полезным другим пользователям StackOverflow.

Comment: @KAGGDesign понятия не имею как оформить ответ, так как кода пока нет, ответить не могу. Может быть, позже дам ответ на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: А я и не говорю, что сейчас. Будет код - вернитесь. Мне лично вопрос показался интересным, иметь на него ответ было бы не лишним.

Comment: @KAGGDesign замётано) вернусь.

Comment: +1 за вопрос. Ждём ответа